# From Hibernate (JPA) + Tomcat to DataNucleus (JPA) + GAE: What changes are required in my models to work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa, datanucleus

I have a fully functional web application that uses GWT (2.5.0), Hibernate (with JPA flavor) on Tomcat 6. I now want to convert this application to run on the Google App Engine (GAE) (I have 1.7.6). GAE uses DataNucleus and there all hell begins as I have to convert from Hibernate to either JDO or JPA (I chose the latter as I was already using JPA for my models), thus using EntityManager.

I've done the conversion from `Hibernate Session` to the `EntityManager`,  `Transaction` became `EntityTransaction`, `beginTransaction()` became `getTransaction()` and I had to add a `begin()` after it, `saveOrUpdate` became `merge`, `delete` became `remove`  etc. etc. The problems come with the mappings.

In Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("extend")
public class Admin extends User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_id")
    @IndexColumn(name="users_index")
    private List<User> users;

    //...
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="admin_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Admin admin;

    //...
}
```

Well, for start I am not allowed to use an id of type long (or Long) with @OneToMany/@ManyToOne/other relations so my options were `Key` or an encoded String. `Key` I am not allowed to use in GWT (read about resmarksystems gwt jar files but this seems like the wrong way to do it/a hack, correct me if I am wrong) so encoded string I figured is the way to go:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("extend")
public class Admin extends User implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="admin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users;

    //...
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@MappedSuperclass //Had to add this or exception: Found inheritance strategy "new-table" on Admin.  This strategy is not supported in this context. Please see the documentation for information on using inheritance with JPA: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html#Inheritance
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    protected String id;

    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.pk-id", value="true")
    protected Long keyId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Admin admin;

    //...
}
```

This only gives me these warnings:

```
15:58:51,181 WARN  [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Meta-data warning for Admin.users: Error in meta-data for Admin.users : The datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first access.  You can modify this warning by setting the datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior property in your config.  A value of NONE will silence the warning.  A value of ERROR will turn the warning into an exception.
15:58:51,182 WARN  [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Meta-data warning for Admin.admin: Error in meta-data for User.admin : The datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first access.  You can modify this warning by setting the datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior property in your config.  A value of NONE will silence the warning.  A value of ERROR will turn the warning into an exception.
```

One main concern I have is, how will I be able to query my datastore using the above? In Hibernate, for example, when I wanted to get all the users of a given admin (admin_id) I would do something like:

```
    Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from " + User.class.getName() + " where admin_id='" + id + "'");
```

Using the encoded string as an id, can I simply do:

```
    Query queryResult = em.createQuery("select from " + User.class.getName() + " where admin_id='" + id + "'");
```

Where does the `keyId` come into the picture? From my understanding you have to set a value to it before I call `merge` or `persist` and given that value, my encoded string `id` is generated. Do I have this right? And what should that value be when I set it before persistance of the object? Do I have to provide a different value when I am updating my record? Could I have the same keyId for multiple records? I guess not (given the following code).

To show what I mean assume the following:

```
@Entity
public class Log implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; //can't use long or I get another exception here...

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
    private LogType type;


    public Log(LogType type, Admin admin, String message, long timestamp) {
        this();
        this.type = type;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    //...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class LogType implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    protected String id;

    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.pk-id", value="true")
    protected Long keyId;

    private String name;


    public LogType(Long id, String name) {
        this();
        this.keyId = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, let's say I crate a new LogType (I have an enum LogTypeEnum for log types):

public static LogType INFO = new LogType(String.valueOf(LogTypeEnum.INFO.ordinal()), "INFO");

then when I try to insert the following in the database:

```
Log myLog = new Log(INFO, admin, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
tx.begin();
em.merge(myLog);
tx.commit();
```

the first time it works fine (well, only if `ordinal` is not 0... it doesn't like 0 `keyId` apprently) and creates both a `LogType` and a `Log` record in the database, and my LogType type_id has the value: `Log(10)/LogType(11)`. I suppose that 10 is my actual log id and that 11 is my actual LogType id. Note that I clear the tables every time so it's not the 11th entry in the table. There is only one record on each table.

**The 2nd time** I call the above code (without clearing the tables), I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Attempt to assign child with key "Log(10)/LogType(11)" to parent with key "Log(no-id-yet)". Parent keys are immutable
```

Note that the 2nd time, the LogType INFO contained inside myLog does have an id (an encoded string), as it was already stored from the first run.

I searched for this and found nothing that explains the error or solution. It seems like it does not want to write another Log with the same LogType. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for reading!